# HTML form directing to a friendly URL

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to implement a friendly URL that has multiple variables using mod_rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311160/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-a-friendly-url-that-has-multiple-variables-usin)

I'm using `mod_rewrite` in my site for friendly URLs which works great. When using a form to add a variable to `$_REQUEST` it's being called in the regular format, and not the friendly one.
My form is something simple like `<input type="text" class="searchbox" id='searchid' name="query" value=""/>`
It now does directs to `www.someurl.com?query="form data"`.

I would like it to direct to a "friendly URL", something like:

```
www.someurl.com/query/"form data"
```

How can I do that in PHP?

Comment: Here's a good reference that might help you:  http://www.phpriot.com/articles/search-engine-urls

Comment: @Amy well actually I used that reference to build my friendly-url in the first place and now am handling the form redirection which still leads to the simple url like before. @yes123 I only saw an answer about doing this in phyton, and would like a php solution. Did I miss it?

Comment: What about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367987/seo-php-how-to-convert-form-submit-url-get-method-without-javascript-seo-frien

Answer (score -2):

Why not put every thing in a POST request?

like this

```
<form method='post' action='/'>
   <input type='text' name='data' value='some value' />
</form>
```

the result in _request will be

array(
  'data' => 'some value'
)

and you still retain your url structure.